# inserted float value unrounds itself on submit

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In an asp.gridview edit mode you can edit a no. of days field, on submit click it updates a table field (float data type) on sql server database. When I enter 1.5 and click submit it inserts exactly 1.5. But when I enter any other value like 1.6 it becomes 1.5999786 on submit. Why is that ? How can I make the table accept the value entered as it is.

Comment: Because floats are approximate values. Don't use them when you want accurate results.

Comment: `num_col as decimal(10, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not an interface issue but a database structure issue.

float data type is an approximate data type; that means that the value stored is not the one you enter but the closest approximation of that value that can be handled by the datatype.

if you need to store the value as is you have to choose a different datatype; decimal is a good choice.

there are many articles online explaining [differences between decimal and float](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/29/sql-server-difference-and-explanation-among-decimal-float-and-numeric/).

you can also find [usage guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187912%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on ms website.